# Richfaces 4.1 push without JMS?

Tags: richfaces

I used a4j:push in the RF3.2 branch but with RF4.1 it seems to be a bit more complicated. Esspecially the demand for a JMS system is something that needs some studying. While studying I read that JMS is no longer needed but I can't find any demo's. I located the how-to and the demo code in the nightly build but they all seem to use JMS.

Without JMS seems to be a lot simpler :)

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Milo van der Zee

Answer (score 0):

From the Richfaces 4.1 [Component Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#sect-Component_Reference-a4jpush-Using_Push_without_JMS):

> 3.8.6. Using Push without JMS
>
> Since JMS coupling may be unwanted in certain cases, RichFaces
>   provides a switch to turn off the JMS integration:
>
> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>org.richfaces.push.jms.disable</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

Just add the above context param to your web.xml use the push component without JMS.

Comment: Yes, I know that and I already have that setting, but what next? I don't know how to produce events. Some kind of example would be very nice or could I just use the IRC demo and remove the atmosphere library?

Answer (score 0):

try RichFaces 4.1 Component Reference again,
there are two samples of usage (TopicsContext and CDI):

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#sect-Component_Reference-a4jpush-Using_TopicsContext_to_publish_message

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I have correct code now but it still does not work. See my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881137/richfaces-4-1-and-a4jpush-get-it-working).

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is an old post, but I can see that this thread is one of the top search for this topic.

If you are using Servlet 3.0, no changes in `web.xml` is required.

First, you need to install atmosphere with the right version. The project that I have worked on is using `Richfaces 4.3.6.Final`. The version of atmosphere it is compatible is `1.0.17`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can start using the `TopicContext` to send notification to the subscribers from the managed bean. Here is how I publish data to the `TopicContext`.

```
TopicKey topicKey = new TopicKey("sometopic");
TopicsContext topicsContext = TopicsContext.lookup();

try {
    topicsContext.publish(topicKey, "somenewdata");
} catch (MessageException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you simply need include the push component in the subscribing page.

```
<a4j:push address="sometopic">
    <a4j:ajax event="dataavailable" oncomplete="someJsMethodToExecuteAfterGettingNotified();"/>
</a4j:push>
```

Once the setup is success, you can simply call `TopicContext#publish` anywhere in the managed bean so that the pages that are subscribing to the topic will be automatically notified.